# Mathematicas: How to solve equation in terms of the variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a quick question. Say you got x+y=2x, and you want to solve this equation in terms of y as some function of x in mathematica, how do you do that?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/34039/

Comment: I need to know how to do it in mathematica

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html

Comment: This question does not demonstrate any effort to solve the problem using available online resources such as a web search.

Comment: `Clear[x, y]; eq = x + y == 2 x; Solve[eq, y]`

Answer (score 1):

just use the [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) function. In your case it becomes :

`Solve[x + y == 2 x, y]`
that gives:
`{{y -> x}}`